# Cannot import X509 v3 certificate

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, x509

I need to validate X509v3 certificate that comes to me as plain text and I'm trying to use this code:

```
public static bool Validate(string certText)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[certText.Length * sizeof(char)];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(certText.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        try
        {
            var cert = new X509Certificate(bytes);
            var cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);
            return cert2.Verify();
        }
        catch(CryptographicException cex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I get an exception with message "Cannot find reqested object" on this row:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate(bytes);
```

Here is my certificate:

```
Bag Attributes
    Microsoft Local Key set: <No Values>
    localKeyID: 01 00 00 00 
    friendlyName: le-cb9ddb3f-ae3b-49a3-8f44-f106f442974d
    Microsoft CSP Name: Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider
Key Attributes
    X509v3 Key Usage: 10 
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
*****
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 01 00 00 00 
    friendlyName: xn--drmtteslger-z8ar8v_dk_2014-09-05
subject=/C=DK/postalCode=8920/L=Randers/street=Normansvej 1/O=DanDomain A/S/OU=Webshop/OU=Hosted by Dandomain A/S/OU=InstantSSL/CN=d\xC3\xB8rm\xC3\xA5ttes\xC3\xA6lger.dk
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO High-Assurance Secure Server CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
*****
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I have tried different ways to create certificate from text/bytes/file/etc, but they all fails at the same point.

Comment: There is a detailed explanation at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/210576/RSA-private-key-import-from-PEM-format-in-Csharp) that you may find useful. Should read it and understand it, but there's ready code as well. Crew from OpenSSL made a non-standard extension, so a non-standard solution is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like problem was in sections order, when I swaped Certificate and Private key sections - everything works like a charm.

UPD: C# cannot import private key from PEM file, so he will simply ignore this section, but it requires certificate section to be the first in file.

Comment: Hum, so where did you get this text form of certificate which fails verification "out of the box"? Edit a certificate in notepad is something seems unusual.

Comment: @kennyzx I've got it from my customer, he said that openssl tool have generated it in such form